# PHPUnit reports error on assignment of exception

Tags: phpunit

I just made some changes that resulted in PHPUnit reporting a large number of errors. Following the stack trace, I arrived at the following assignment statement: `$this->_default_exception = new \RuntimeException('No value.');` PHPUnit reports this, not surprisingly, as `RuntimeException: No value.` This is clearly the assignment of an exception to a property, not the throwing of an exception. Why is PHPUnit reporting an error here?

Comment: Can you share the code you're running that causes the error?

Comment: Aside from the code above, not really.

Comment: I've actually observed this in multiple situations.